# variable from one function to other in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

There are 2 functions one compacting the non existing schools to view and view should return department of the following majors to the new school function. While inserting in the DB, I need 2 array one from the input and other from the above function.
But the array is returning no value,shown above

```
protected $school_notFound = [];

public function insert(Request $request) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($majors_array1); $i++) {
        if (School::where('major', '=', $majors_array1[$i])->exists()) {

        } else {
            array_push($this->school_notFound, $majors_array1[$i]);
            $this->school_notFound = array_unique($this->school_notFound);
        }
    }
    $school_notFound = $this->school_notFound;
    return view('enter-school-dept', compact('school_array', 'school_notFound'));
}

public function New_School(Request $request) {
    print_r($this->school_notFound);
    $New_school = $request->input('selected_school');
    print_r($New_school);
}
```

the results are

```
Array ( ) 
Array ( [0] => SOB [1] => SOB [2] => CMN )
```

Comment: Post the code in your question, don't post pictures of the code. Also try to better explain what you mean.

Comment: By the way; you are passing the `school_notFound` variable to the `enter-school-dept` view and not to the `New_School` function.

Comment: here the thing is,i have entered bunch of schools if it exists then it gets the department,if not exists which are not existing i have kept in a array nd compact in view nd i am getting the input of the department from the view which is then received in the New_school function as i dont need the majors to be given again.to insert it in db i need the school_not found array in new_school function,thn i can match the index numbers of 2 array and insert it

Answer (score 0):

I take from the code you provided that someone will fill a form to call your second function New_School().

Since we can not pass array through forms we need to serialize the array first. You can use serialize() for this or json_encode(), in my example i use json_encode(). Than we set a hidden field in our form which will carry the serialized jsonString. When the user submits the form we can retrieve the jsonString from the request and use json_decode() to convert it back to an array. In case you used serialize(), you can use unserialize() to convert back to an array.

**PHP**

```
class testController extends Controller
{
    //json_encode the array so we can put it in a hidden field in our form
    public function test(){
        $array = ['test', 'test2'];

        $json = json_encode($array);

        return view('test')->with('json', $json);
    }

    //json_decode the jsonString back to an array
    public function test2(Request $request){
        $array2 = json_decode($request->input('json'));

        print_r($array2);
    }
}
```

The view:

**html**

```
<form action="{{route('test2')}}" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="json" value="{{$json}}"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Also a tip: be consistent in how you name your variables. Either use camelCase or use snake_case don't mix them.

---

As requested an example with your code:

**PHP**

```
// This is not needed
//protected $school_notFound = [];

public function insert(Request $request) {
    $school_notFound = [];

    for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($majors_array1); $i++) {
        if (School::where('major', '=', $majors_array1[$i])->exists()) {

        } else {
            array_push($school_notFound, $majors_array1[$i]);
            $school_notFound = array_unique($school_notFound);
        }
    }

    $school_not_found_json = json_encode($school_notFound);

    return view('enter-school-dept')
        ->with('school_notFound', $school_notFound)
        ->with('school_array', $school_array)
        ->with('school_not_found_json', $school_not_found_json);
}

public function New_School(Request $request) {
    $array2 = json_decode($request->input('school_not_found_json'));
    print_r($array2);
    $New_school = $request->input('selected_school');
    print_r($New_school);
}
```

**html**

```
<form action="" method="">
    <input type="hidden" name="school_not_found_json" value="{{$school_not_found_json}}">

    @foreach ($school_notFound as $notfound) 
    <option value='{{$notfound}}'>{{$notfound}}</option>
    <input list="browsers" name="selected_school[]" /></label>
    <datalist id="browsers" name="selected_school[]">
    @endforeach

    @foreach ($school_array as $school) 
    <option value='{{$school}}'>{{$school}}</option>
    @endforeach

    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: thanks a lot for your tip i will follow it from now on wards.and i have created an instant but as protected not as private

Comment: Ok I misread the question. What is happening in your code is you set the attribute for the class in the first function than you go to a view. When returning to the class to call the second function the class get instantiated again so the class attribute is set again to [] which you have specified. Since you are sending the $school_notFound array to the view, wouldn't it be best to send it back to the second function that needs it?

Comment: i am kinda confused with your comment.i have decleared a global type variable above the functions i have used it first in function 1 nd filled it with data in a array form.and i just want to get that array data in 2nd function thats it.i am getting the array but i am getting no values its empty.

Comment: When the first function goes to the view the instance of the controller class is terminated. This means when you go back from the view to the second function a new instance is created where the value of $school_notFound is set to an empty array again. This explains why upon calling the second function the array is empty. What you could do is when you call the second function from the view you add the array to the request. That way you can retrieve the array from $request and do what you need to.

Comment: i can understand what u r telling me to do.but i am confused how to do so.can you give me an example.as u gave before for the attribute one.or u can copy my code given above

Comment: I edited my first example. If my assumption is wrong about the user submitting a form to call the second function, than you need to provide more context so I can help you better.

Comment: for($i=0;$i<sizeof($majors_array1);$i++){
if (School::where('major', '=', $majors_array1[$i])->exists()){}else{array_push( $this->school_notFound, $majors_array1[$i]); $school_notFound=$this->school_notFound;return view('enter-school-dept', compact('school_array','school_notFound'));}    view            @foreach ($school_notFound as $notfound) <option value='{{$notfound}}'>{{$notfound}}</option><input list="browsers" name="selected_school[]" /></label><datalist id="browsers" name="selected_school[]">@foreach ($school_array as $school) <option value='{{$school}}'>{{$school}}</option>

Comment: Thats a bit hard to read, but I tried to implement my example into your code. Hope it helps